# using regex to validate input formatting in C#

Tags: c#, regex, formatting

This is a super basic question (I am brain dead today):

How do I validate in input using regexes, to see:
1) if the input is in a certain form
2) if the input is all caps (just casting the input to caps is not feasible for this)

I want ot make sure my inputs are in the form XX_XX. Here isi what I have:

```
public bool IsKosher(string input)
{
    Regex r = new Regex(input);
    if(r.Matches([A-Z]_[A-Z]))
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;     
}
```

Any ideas why it's not compiling?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing double quotes, you put parameters in wrong places, and you do not need an `if` statement:

```
public bool IsKosher(string input) {
    return Regex.IsMatch(input, "[A-Z]{2}_[A-Z]{2}");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Quotes?  A missing closing parenthesis?  Matches not returning a boolean?  Swapping string parameters?  All will cause your code not to compile.

Though you may want this if it is "XX_XX":

```
var r = new Regex("[A-Z]{2}_[A-Z]{2}");
return r.IsMatch(input);
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to put [A-Z]_[A-Z] between quotes like this:

```
if(r.Matches("[A-Z]_[A-Z]")
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Quotes.
2. Two characters on either side of the `_`.
3. The `Regex` constructor takes the pattern; the `Matches` method takes the string to search.
4. The `Matches` method returns a `MatchCollection`. `IsMatch` returns a boolean.

Like so:

```
if (Regex.IsMatch(input, "[A-Z]{2}_[A-Z]{2}")
```